# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute a *PL/SQL statement* in MySQL. but, when I try to create a table it shows a syntax error. I get the following **error**

```
CREATE TABLE supplier(supid NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY, suppname VARCHAR2(15));
```

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY, suppname VARCHAR2(15))' at line 1
```

full code is as follows:

```
DROP TABLE supplier; 
DROP SEQUENCE practical2_sequence; 
*/ 
CREATE TABLE supplier(supid NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY, suppname VARCHAR2(15)); 
CREATE SEQUENCE practical2_sequence START WITH 1 MAXVALUE 100; 
BEGIN 
LOOP 
INSERT INTO supplier VALUES(practical2_sequence.NEXTVAL, 1); 
EXIT WHEN practical2_sequence.CURRVAL >= 100; 
END LOOP; 
END; 
/ 
SELECT * FROM supplier;
```

Help me, as I am not that experienced in MySQL.

Comment: `NUMBER` is not a valid data type. That should be `INT(5)`

Comment: `PL/SQL` is for Oracle, not MySQL.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have `SEQUENCE`. You declare the ID with the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute.

Comment: There is no varchar2 or number in mysql. There is a varchar and numeric though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be trying to use Oracle syntax with MySQL.

MySQL doesn't have sequences, it uses the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute of the column. When inserting, either assign `NULL` to the column or leave it out of the column list, and it will get the next value in the sequence.

MySQL doesn't have the `NUMBER` datatype, it uses `INT`. It doesn't have `VARCHAR2`, just `VARCHAR`.

```
DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS supplier; 
CREATE TABLE supplier(
    supid INT(5) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    suppname VARCHAR(15)
);
WHILE counter < 100 DO
    INSERT INTO supplier (suppname) VALUES('1');
END WHILE;
```

Note that variable declarations and `WHILE` loops can only be used inside stored procedures, not as ordinary queries.

Comment: `DECLARE` may be used in compound statement only, and it must be placed before any other statements in the block.